# sencha cmd won't make an .appcache file

Tags: caching, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, offline-mode, senchatouch-2.4

I'm trying to make my app run offline with caching. And I have the default appCache section in my app.json:

```
/**
 * Used to automatically generate cache.manifest (HTML 5 application cache manifest) file when you build
 */
"appCache": {
    /**
     * List of items in the CACHE MANIFEST section
     */
    "cache": [
        "index.html"
    ],
    /**
     * List of items in the NETWORK section
     */
    "network": [
        "*"
    ],

        /**
         * List of items in the FALLBACK section
         */
        "fallback": []
    },
```

Yet in my final build I only have the resources folder, app.js and index.html
I already upgraded Sencha Cmd from 4 to 5 to the newest 5.1.1.39. So it looks like I made a mistake somewhere in my config.
It does not matter if I refer the file in my Index.html:

```
<html manifest="cache.appcache" lang="en-US">
```

I have the file in my development folder, so during development it works fine. I could copy the file manually, but that's not a good long term solution.

Edit: a fresh sencha application does create a cache.appcache file. So I must have broken it somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by specifying specific build for native platforms in the app.json. Commenting them out caused Sencha Cmd to revert to the default build and make an cache.appcache file.

Comment: Good catch. I just wonder what is the correct setting: have or not cache manifest for the native build?